# How many fragments do you need to get Fragment Skills?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I noticed that I got two skills when I first got to Serendipity with ~20 fragments, but since then I didn't get any more Fragment Skills until I got to the final level and had maybe 40 or 50 fragments when I got two more. What determines when I get them? Is it just a flat number? If so, how many does it take for a skill? Otherwise, how does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragment skills are tied to specific milestones throughout the game: completing the main storyline, completing certain episodes, collecting a set of fragments that relate to each other, and so on.

These are the ones I've been able to find:

- Two you get right off the bat in Serendipity: *Mog's Manifestation* and *Haggler*
- Two you get for completing episode 5: *Anti-grav Jump* and *Bargain Hunter*
- One you get for completing the main storyline: *Paradox scope*
- One you get for getting all the fragments in the game: *Clock Master*

A [guide by Krystal109 on GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/619315-final-fantasy-xiii-2/faqs/63734?page=3#section215) lists the locations of all the rest, but if you happen to collect all 160 fragments, you'll wind up getting the vast majority of the skills.

Comment: btw, I contacted the author, and she said she doesn't mind if you copy information from her guide as long as you give her credit.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. I just reached the 135-140 mark, and I've gotten more Fragment Skills in the last 25-30 I've found than in the previous 100+. Some are gotten by getting specific fragment sets; ie Battlemania. For Battlemania, which allows you higher chances of finding rare monsters, you have to get the final Fragment off the Paradox Professor questline in Academia 400AF. (You have to get 100% map discovery on each location, which often requires covering the entire map of an area in 2-3 timelines; Academia itself is one of these.)
For Rolling in CP, you need to do all the Fragments in all timelines for Bresha Ruins and Yaschas Massif.
Here's a link with them all.
http://mycheats.1up.com/view/section/3175228/32181/final_fantasy_xiii_2/ps3